# How to rename multiple files by replacing string in file name?

Tags: scripting, rename

I have basically splitted one file into 8 files.

```
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_2_2_20170502094536.dat  #Original File
```

I got 8 new files as below filename.

```
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_2_2_20170502094536.dat.aa
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_2_2_20170502094536.dat.ab
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_2_2_20170502094536.dat.ac
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_2_2_20170502094536.dat.ad
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_2_2_20170502094536.dat.ae
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_2_2_20170502094536.dat.af
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_2_2_20170502094536.dat.ag
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_2_2_20170502094536.dat.ah
```

I want to rename these files as below name:

```
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_1_8_20170502094536.dat
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_2_8_20170502094536.dat
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_3_8_20170502094536.dat
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_4_8_20170502094536.dat
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_5_8_20170502094536.dat
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_6_8_20170502094536.dat
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_7_8_20170502094536.dat
DA_TRP_TOTAL-SHIPPED_v1_DNH_8_8_20170502094536.dat
```

How can I do it in unix shell scripting?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended tool for rename bunches of files is `rename`, this will do your job.

```
rename -n 'our $i++; s/_DNH_\K\d+_\d+(.*)\..*/${i}_8$1/' DA*.dat.*
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select right tool at first to spiting.

```
split -a 1 --numeric-suffixes=1 -n 8 myfile myFile_from_8_
```

this will split `myFile` into the 8 parts with name starts with `myFile_from_8_N` (The `N` is from 1-8)

Or even you can simulate the split with `awk` command as like below with X number of records in each split-ed files (in sample `X=100`, means 100 records per files):

```
awk 'NR%100==1{ file=sprintf("myFile_from_8_%d",((++c)) )} {print >file}' myFile
```